# probability question about brownian motion

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

Assume $W_{t}$ is a standard Brownian Motion, calculate the the probability that $W_{t}*W_{2t}$ is negative, i.e., $P(W_{t}*W_{2t}<0)$. I find it tricky to calculate the probability.Thank you.

Comment: Looks like homework. What have you tried? You probably want to use the fact that $W$ has independant increments.

Comment: This is conceptually simple, but you may need some tedious computations.

Comment: I have tried to solve like: $P(W_{t}*W_{2t}<0)=P(W_{t}<0,W_{2t}>0)+P(W_{t}>0,W_{2t}<0)=$$P(W_{2t}>0|W_{t}<0)P(W_{t}<0)+P(W_{2t}<0|W_{t}>0)P(W_{t}>0)=P(W_{2t}-W_{t}+W_{t}>0|W_{t}<0)P(W_{t}<0)+P(W_{2t}-W_{t}+W_{t}<0|W_{t}>0)P(W_{t}>0)$.

Comment: I have no idea how to continue, Is there any hint? Or are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your decomposition is correct. I will show here the computation  for one term:
\begin{align*}
P(W_t < 0, W_{2t} >0) &= P(W_t < 0, W_{2t}-W_t > -W_t)\\
&= E\Big(E\big(\mathbb{1}_{\{W_t < 0\}}\mathbb{1}_{\{W_{2t}-W_t > -W_t\}}\mid W_t\big)\Big)\\
&= E\Big(\mathbb{1}_{\{W_t < 0\}} \Phi\big(W_t/\sqrt{t}\big)\Big) \\
&=E\Big(\mathbb{1}_{\{W_t/\sqrt{t} < 0\}} \Phi\big(W_t/\sqrt{t}\big)\Big) \\
&=\int_{-\infty}^0 \phi(x) \Phi(x) dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\Phi(x)^2\mid_{-\infty}^0\\
&=\frac{1}{8},
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align*}
\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}
\end{align*}
is the density of a standard normal random variable, and $\Phi(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function.

Comment: In the first line $P(W_t < 0, W_{2t} >0) = E(W_t < 0, W_{2t}-W_t > -W_t),$ why is probability changed to expectation? Which result are you using?

Comment: @Idonknow: Note that $P(A) = E(\pmb{1}_A)$.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this equality. But there is no indicator function in $E[W_t<0, W_{2t} - W_t > - W_t].$

Comment: It is a typo. See the revision.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 6):

Since $W_{2t}-W_{t}$ is independent of $W_t$ and has the same law as $W_{2t-t}=W_t$ we only have to compute
$$P(X(X+Y)<0)$$
where $(X,Y)$ follows a bivariate normal distribution (with zero correlation). From there you can split the probability in two cases : either $X<0$ and $X+Y>0$ or the opposite. The two events have the same probability since $(-X,-Y)\sim (X,Y)$. You are left with the computation of
$$ P(X<0,X+Y>0)$$
since the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is invariant by rotation around the z-axis) this probability can be computed geometrically (think cutting a cake, the cake being the bivariate density) : it is equal to $1/8$. The final result is thus $1/4$.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving an intuitive answer. Just a bit confused that do you mean $(-X, -X-Y) \sim (X, X+Y)$ instead of $(-X, -X-Y) \sim (X, Y)$

Comment: That was a typo sorry.